# Highlight text while TextToSpeech is playing

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I have text displaying on a screen and in my code I am trying to highlight the text before TextToSpeech starts speaking and when it finishes change the color back to its original. However, it never changes the color to blue or at least thats what it seems like.

This is what starts the TextToSpeech

```
ImageView playButton = (ImageView) blankPage.findViewById(R.id.play_button);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

                                  {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onClick(View v) {
                                          findHighlightedWords();


                                          mTts.setSpeechRate(0.60f);
                                          play(mWordsToSpeechBank, mHighlightedTextViews);
   }
}
```

This is the play method

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

private void play (ArrayList<String> playMe, ArrayList<TextView> highlightedWords){

    if (playMe.size() > 0) {
        final ArrayList<String> wordsToPlay = new ArrayList<String>(playMe);
        final ArrayList<TextView> highLightedTextView = new ArrayList<TextView>(highlightedWords);

        final TextView textView = highLightedTextView.get(0);

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
        });

        String getFirst = wordsToPlay.get(0);
        wordsToPlay.remove(0);
        highLightedTextView.remove(0);

        mTts.speak(getFirst, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

        do {

        } while (mTts.isSpeaking());

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }
        });
        play(wordsToPlay, mHighlightedTextViews);
    }
}
```

When I look at the log it says 
"Choreographer﹕ Skipped 206 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Comment: Click handlers run on the UI thread, and your `while (mTts.isSpeaking());` loop causes your app to hang the UI thread until TTS has finished speaking. The TextToSpeech.speak() method is asynchronous -- you should be using an [UtteranceProgressListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener.html) callback to find out whether speech has finished.

Comment: Thank you!! This worked and makes perfect sense!

Comment: You can also use [BackgroundSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BackgroundColorSpan.html) to highlight a region within a single TextView, rather than making multiple TextViews. I use setSelection() in [TypeAndSpeak](https://github.com/aviverette/typeandspeak/blob/master/src/com/googamaphone/typeandspeak/TypeAndSpeak.java#L855) because I'm using an EditText, but the idea is similar.